# Employee Stock Option Shares - What happens when the company gets acquired

Tags: stocks, india, employee-stock-options

The company I worked for 20 years ago had given me stock options. When I resigned from the company, I had purchased the options that had vested with me. Subsequently bonus shares were allotted and my total holdings multiplied a few times in 5-6 years. After that I have not received any communication regarding the same.

2 years ago the company got acquired by another company and few months ago the acquiring company got acquired by another company. I had no communication of any of these events at the time they happened.

Subsequently I learnt of all these developments through an ex-colleague, that the vested shares of employees were paid in cash (only? - not sure).

Would like to know -

1. Am I eligible for a payment, although it is delayed by 1.5-2 years?
   What are my rights ?
2. In case I need to pursue this matter, whom should I contact - my old
   employer company (no contact information available) or the acquiring
   company ?

My employer company was privately held, unlisted company. I do not know the status of the acquiring companies though.

Thanks for any guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had purchased the options that had vested with me

Re-Check this. Do you have the share certificates issued under your name. Assuming you have;

> that the vested shares of employees were paid in cash (only? - not sure).

All shares [including vested shares of employees] can be forced to cash, it would be part of the deal between old and new company.

> Am I eligible for a payment, although it is delayed by 1.5-2 years? What are my rights ?

Yes you are within your rights to claim the payment.

> In case I need to pursue this matter, whom should I contact - my old employer company (no contact information available) or the acquiring company ?

The current acquiring company.

Ideally they should have a record of who owned how many shares in the first company, how they got translated into shares of second company, cash paid out of each share held in second company.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. Yes I have all the share certificates.